# find the cause of file corruption when copying files to a network share on an Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, samba, ext4, corruption

I am copying files from my SD card to my Ubuntu server via Windows 7 using a network drive.

The problem is that sometimes, 2 files out of 150, are corrupted during transfer.

See here 2 example files in hex compare, left side original, right side how it is stored on server. They differ in ~10kB. In the second example you can see 00's added.

[image: File 1 - .JPG example]

[image: File 2 - .CR2 example]

I don't know what could cause this. So i am asking for any advice how to narrow down the possible error source.

I think it is not the hardware itself, because 2 drives are affected.

Network connection is also not the issue, this is cable bound and i had never problems on that level.

My wife has the feeling that sometimes the bug also appears when working on files in Picasa. But i can't say that for sure.

My guess is, that it is some sort of race condition bug on either ext4 fs or samba or mount.

Here some system information, which might help:

The affected drives are:

```
UUID="bc57f0fd-c16d-450e-83aa-4b7faace655c" /media/FOTOS2/ ext4 defaults 2
UUID="aacc7c57-8997-42c3-a2fc-648fe5a9009c" /media/WDRED2TB/ ext4 defaults 2
```

Here the complete fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=9978d40a-b90d-49e1-ab7a-002cc0577120 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=AA12-9F54  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=bba8a1b5-a7da-44a2-a220-23a69c73e6ab none            swap    sw              0       0


UUID="bc57f0fd-c16d-450e-83aa-4b7faace655c" /media/FOTOS2/ ext4 defaults 2
UUID="aacc7c57-8997-42c3-a2fc-648fe5a9009c" /media/WDRED2TB/ ext4 defaults 2
UUID="ba87bd76-a34a-45a5-8268-4de331ebf72f" /media/RAID/ ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Here the 'mount' output

```
/dev/sde2 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
/dev/sde1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/FOTOS2 type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/WDRED2TB type ext4 (rw)
/dev/md0p1 on /media/RAID type ext4 (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=piotre)
```

The system is a

```
piotre@SERVER:~$ uname -a
Linux SERVER 3.13.0-46-generic #79-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 10 20:06:50 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dumpe2fs gives for one of the drives:

```
Filesystem volume name:   WDRED2TB
Last mounted on:          /media/WDRED2TB
Filesystem UUID:          aacc7c57-8997-42c3-a2fc-648fe5a9009c
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
Filesystem features:      has_journal ext_attr resize_inode dir_index filetype needs_recovery extent flex_bg sparse_super large_file huge_file uninit_bg dir_nlink extra_isize
Filesystem flags:         signed_directory_hash
Default mount options:    (none)
Filesystem state:         clean
Errors behavior:          Continue
Filesystem OS type:       Linux
Inode count:              122101760
Block count:              488378385
Reserved block count:     24418919
Free blocks:              36947951
Free inodes:              121834982
First block:              0
Block size:               4096
Fragment size:            4096
Reserved GDT blocks:      907
Blocks per group:         32768
Fragments per group:      32768
Inodes per group:         8192
Inode blocks per group:   512
RAID stride:              1
Flex block group size:    16
Filesystem created:       Wed May  1 12:47:05 2013
Last mount time:          Tue Apr  7 15:27:31 2015
Last write time:          Tue Apr  7 15:27:31 2015
Mount count:              169
Maximum mount count:      25
Last checked:             Mon Jul 21 21:11:14 2014
Check interval:           15552000 (6 months)
Next check after:         Sat Jan 17 20:11:14 2015
Lifetime writes:          2513 GB
Reserved blocks uid:      0 (user root)
Reserved blocks gid:      0 (group root)
First inode:              11
Inode size:               256
Required extra isize:     28
Desired extra isize:      28
Journal inode:            8
Default directory hash:   half_md4
Directory Hash Seed:      9e898ed8-9275-4e6f-9dd6-431190f4b932
Journal backup:           inode blocks
Jounaleigenschaften:         journal_incompat_revoke
Journalgrösse:            128M
Journal-Länge:            32768
Journal-Sequenz:          0x00028de6
Journal-Start:            1
```

First i tried modifying smb.conf (sync always and strict sync) but it did not help.
Here the current smb.conf

```
[global]
workgroup=WORKGROUP
server string=%h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
netbios name=SERVER
dns proxy=no
log file=/var/log/samba/log.%m
max log size=1000
syslog=0
panic action=/usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
server role=standalone server
map to guest=bad user
usershare allow guests=yes
security=share
force user=nobody
guest account=nobody
socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_RCVBUF=65536 SO_SNDBUF=65536
strict syn = yes
sync always = yes
```

Comment: Run a memory test on both machines. There's an option for that in the Ubuntu boot menu. Let it run for at least one full pass (overnight should do it).

Comment: Memtest says memory is fine

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you've figured it out yet, but you misspelled "strict sync" in your smb.conf (forgot the 'c'). Also, "sync always" will have no effect if strict sync is not enabled (which it won't be in this case due to the error).